# A good explanation of Eloquent for Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am learning Laravel 5.2 and can see the huge potential of Eloquent, but I find some of the tutorials rather assuming that one understands things. For example I have a table authors and a table items. Obviously authors has many items and items have 1 author.

The various examples and videos tend to jump over this and what I would like to understand is the rules and a good source for setting up the relationships and more complex queries otherwise I will have to resort to using PDO classes of a more trandition manner.

Can someone recommend something please?

Comment: The laravel doc has plenty of examples: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: I've look at this in detail but it is vague

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the Laravel documentation has improved a lot and the topic of Eloquent is quite clear. For instance, your example is clearly a one to many relationship.

```
class Author extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

As simple as that and so elegant. Would you mind rephrase what is it that's confusing to you if I am mistaken?